# traits with immutable paramiters in scala

Tags: scala, traits, scala-2.10

I want to make the following example so that Collar is immutable

```
  trait Collar{
    var text:String="";
  }

  class dog(val name:String){
    def bark()=  ...
  }

    val snoopy = new dog("snoopy") with Collar;
    snoopy.text="charley's dog";
    println(snoopy.text)
```

However when I try something like

```
  trait Collar(val text:String){
  }
```

I get the compile time error

```
traits or objects may not have parameters
```

Is there currently a a way to do this?  If not, why not?

Remember, a good dog shouldn't care when it has a Collar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all sure what your real question is, but perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
trait Collar{
  val tagText: String    // 'val', not 'var'; left undefined here
}

class Dog(val name:String) {
  def bark()=  ...
}

val snoopy = new Dog("snoopy") with Collar {
  val tagText= "charley's dog"
}
println(snoopy.tagText)
```

Alternatively, Collar.tagText can be set with an initial/default value AND also be overridden where Dog is instantiated.